# Spring controller: permanent link to article like on Facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring, controller, permalinks

I want add "permalink" feature to my web written in Spring.
If user click to permalink bottom article, Spring must send to user browser page with this one (only one) article with id from url.

For example: http://example.net/article/123

There is my broken code:

```
@Controller
public class ArticleController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleManager am;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/article/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showArticle(@PathVariable int id, Model model,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        String visited = "no";
        try {
            visited = (String) model.asMap().get("visited");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        if (! visited.equals("yes")) {
            Article x = am.findById(id);
            model.addAttribute("article", x);
            redirectAttributes.addAttribute("visited", "yes");          
            return "/article/"+id;          
        }       

        return "redirect:/article/"+id;        
    }
}
```

---

Update:
Like on Facebook wall. If I click on publish date bottom the post, Facebook redirect me to page with only this post: https://www.facebook.com/9gag/posts/205093383022280

Comment: Can you please clarify what does it mean "If user click to permalink bottom article, Spring must send to user browser page with this..."

Comment: Like on Facebook wall. If I click on publish date bottom the post, Facebook redirect me to page with only this post: https://www.facebook.com/9gag/posts/205093383022280